# nvm not changing node version to comply with strapi

Tags: node.js, terminal, strapi, nvm

I am trying to create a new strapi project in my api folder for an ecommerce website project. However no matter what I do to try to change the node version using nvm I still get this error (that it is not compatible to the current version). As you can see below I literally just used nvm to change the node version to 20.0.0 and I got confirmation I was currently using it. Also you can see on my nvm list command that 21.2.0 isn't even installed. I am confused and also a beginner. Am I using nvm wrong? Do I have to delete some previous folder that is somehow making my project think I am using 21.2.0? I am very confused and would appreciate any help.

```
current@0.1.6
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> nvm current
v20.11.0
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> nvm ls 

    20.9.0
    20.5.0
    20.0.0
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> nvm use 20.0.0
Now using node v20.0.0 (64-bit)
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> npx create-strapi-app@latest .         
(node:14736) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternatiternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
You are running Node.js 21.2.0
Strapi requires Node.js >=18.0.0 <=20.x.x
Please make sure to use the right version of Node.
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api>
```

I tried to change the version of nod using nvm and it appeared to change however I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had photoshop which contains node.exe itself. i removed photoshop as well as node_modules in user folder then reinstalled node which helped me.

Comment: ...photoshop? Like, [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop)? How is that relevant?

Comment: it contains nodejs in its folder and its version was higher than mine that was installed manually.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35763705)